# Why does glibc have 2 versions of the same functions?

Tags: glibc

I don't fully understand the versioning mechanism of glibc.

In what cases do the developers decide a function needs a new version, and that function is no longer "backwards compatible" in glibc and a new `GLIBC_2.X` version needs to be introduced?

In the case of a function's prototype change, or an API change, I understand, but what more causes are there?

i.e. fnmatch:

I'm looking at a `readelf` output on my glibc 2.19 and I see 2 versions of fnmatch:

```
151: 000bff40   892 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 fnmatch@GLIBC_2.0
152: 000bff40   892 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 fnmatch@@GLIBC_2.2.3
```

But when I look at glibc's code, I see they are exactly the same function:

```
versioned_symbol (libc, __fnmatch, fnmatch, GLIBC_2_2_3);
#  if SHLIB_COMPAT(libc, GLIBC_2_0, GLIBC_2_2_3)
strong_alias (__fnmatch, __fnmatch_old)
compat_symbol (libc, __fnmatch_old, fnmatch, GLIBC_2_0);
#  endif
```

So why does fnmatch even have 2 versions?
What other causes are there for the developers to start a "new version" of a function?

Comment: [Also posted on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28662607/why-do-glibc-has-2-versions-of-the-same-functions). Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).